# How to enable RecognizerIntent in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, speech-recognition, google-nexus

I am an android newbie and wanted to create a small app that does speech recognition.  I am using an android 4.0.3 emulator to test this.  When I run it, I notice that the emulator does not have recognizer present.  How can I get the a speech recognizer added to the emulator?  I searched for information and the best I got so far was information on how to install it on an HTC emulator whereas I am using a Google Nexus 4.0.3 emulator.  Any help would be much appreciated!